# HeaderStringFormat overrides style outside of Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an application that formats headers to be in all caps.

I'm trying to set the header of some data columns like so:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding ExampleString" HeaderStringFormat="ExampleHeader: {0}" />
```

However something strange is happening. Let's assume ExampleString = "test".

My result is "ExampleHeader: TEST". The binding is being formatted correctly, but the rest of the string is not.

If I try to format the text of the header instead with something like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
      <TextBlock Text="...", StringFormat="..."/>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

Then none of the string is formatted correctly.

Is there a way to format the string correct without the style formatting being messed up?

Comment: Are you familiar with using Converters yet?

Comment: @Tronald do you think that's a good solution for this instance? What's the syntax for adding a converter if the original value is a literal? Like Header="ExampleHeader: "

Comment: Converters are good to be familiar with, and can save you a lot of time when XAML is failing to format correctly. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet may be to use an `IValueConverter`. The string formatting in XAML is often frustrating and not as powerful as what you can do in an `IValueConverter`, so it's good to be familiar with their use anyway.

Here's an example of an `IValueConverter` that would work to your specs.

```
using System.Windows.Data;

public class ExampleToUpperConverter : IValueConverter
{
    //Converts input string and returns new formatted string
    //Input string is your bound "ExampleString" value in your case
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Get the header string value
        var str = value as string;

        //Handle null values
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)){return string.Empty;}

        return string.Format("ExampleHeader: {0}",str.ToUpper());
    }

    //Converts formatted string back to original value
    //Only applicable on input controls, but the method is still required in the class
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ok now that it's built you must declare the converter as a resource in your XAML. You may have a dictionary somewhere. For this example I'm going to put in in your `MainWindow.xaml` and assume your control is also used in your `MainWindow`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ExampleToUpperConverter x:Key="ExampleToUpperConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now you can tap into the `IValueConverter` whenever needed.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding ExampleString, Converter={StaticResource ExampleToUpperConverter}}" />
```

Comment: I didn't think about using converters to solve this problem. I ended up using a ConverterParameter to set the literal text and the Header value to pass the bound string.